# Shodan JSON from python to javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, json

I'm working with the Shodan API and I'm having issues while passing the received JSON to the template (django).

This is the Raw JSON structure:

```
{"matches": [{"city": "Montreal", "updated": "02.02.2013", "ip": "24.48.3.143", "longitude": -73.5833, "data": "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nDate: Sat, 02 Feb 2013 00:41:53 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/1.3.42 (Unix) mod_auth_pam/1.1.1 DAV/1.0.3 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8g\r\nSet-Cookie: iomega=174.79.246.153.26931359765713476; path=/\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n", "country_name": "Canada", "hostnames": [], "country_code": "CA", "country": "DEPRECATED: use country_name", "latitude": 45.5, "os": "Linux 2.6.x", "port": 443}]}
```

And this is the data structure I pass to the template:

```
[{"city": "Montreal", "updated": "02.02.2013", "os": "Linux 2.6.x", "ip": "24.48.3.143", "longitude": -73.5833, "latitude": 45.5, "hostnames": [], "country_code": "CA", "country": "DEPRECATED: use country_name", "country_name": "Canada", "data": "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nDate: Sat, 02 Feb 2013 00:41:53 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/1.3.42 (Unix) mod_auth_pam/1.1.1 DAV/1.0.3 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8g\r\nSet-Cookie: iomega=174.79.246.153.26931359765713476; path=/\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n", "port": 443}]
```

As you can see there are a lot of special chars inside it wich mess up the conversion. Another issue is with "hostnames" child wich is a list of elements (if exist elements)...

Anyone knows how to handle this JSON file in js/jquery with the correct format?
Regards.

EDIT: I was checking the output from my javascript and the special chars passed from the django view to the template are converted to html code and \r\n disapear causing the parsing error:

I compared both json files with: http://json.parser.online.fr/

And the json received from shodan api and manipulated in the view works fine but not the JSON pased to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, as I said in the question when I pass the JSON from the view to the template django converts characters used in JavaScript strings.

The solution is to add the escapejs tag to your variable in the template:

{{ JSON|escapejs}}

Here you can find the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escapejs